# how to add background gif image as splash screen in launch_background.xml in flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, background-image, splash-screen

how to add background .gif_image as splash screen in launch_background.xml in a flutter. The below image shows, I tried to add .gif_image in the 'drawable' folder and add to the background image but still getting errors. Is it the right way that I used to add gif in .XML file or do I have to add some dependency regarding gif in pubspec or Gradle

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lottie for that

here a link describe a full step on it [animation Splash Screen](https://medium.com/swlh/native-splash-screen-in-flutter-using-lottie-121ce2b9b0a4)

dont want to use Lottie ??

there a similiar package Called Rive and there a standalone package for that
[Rive Splash](https://pub.dev/packages/rive_splash_screen)